# How to databind livedata object (android)

Tags: android-databinding, android-livedata, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

Today I've some question about mvvm and databinding on android,

I'm trying to bind object properties on view.

I've an Object (Model) with some properties, by example :

```
public String name;
public String title;
public int value;
```

I've a ViewModel with livedata like this :

```
MutableLiveData<Object> _obj = new MutableLiveData<>();
public LiveData<Object> obj = _obj;
```

And, at last, I've a view like this :

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel">
            type="com.sample.app.viewmodels.MainViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        ... >
        <TextView
            android:text:="@{viewModel.obj.name}"
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I saw that we can do that in a video from "Android Developers" about "LiveData" : https://youtu.be/OMcDk2_4LSk?t=102

She says that its possible in Android studio on 3.1+ versions.
But this is not working for me.

Comment: Have you set the ViewModel in your Activity/Fragment binding? Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture)

Comment: Hi, yes, I use this : binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

Comment: do you also set `binding.viewModel = viewModel`? Can you show the pare where you set these binding parameters

Comment: Yes, I do this : 

`public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        MainFragmentBinding binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }`

Comment: why you create a ```livedata``` from your ```MuteableLiveData```? why donsn't use the ```MuteableLiveData``` for binding?

Comment: Yes it's olso possible, and at the first time it was the case, but it's the same result.

Comment: Finally its working ! but the object fields are not provided by Android Studio. I do this manualy. Another thing does not work, the ui update, when I change a value in field I do a calculation and I'd like to update my textview when the values changes.

Comment: Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, your model class must extend `BaseObservable` class from databinding library. And you have to call `notifyChange()` on each setter method like this:

```java
public class Object extends BaseObservable {
    public String name;
    public String title;
    public int value;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        notifyChange();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcomw... please do upvote my answer if it helped you. :)